# Resetting Bios Password on ASUS Transformer T300L

Tags: motherboard, bios, password-recovery

So, I have a ASUS Transformer Book T300L. I usually set a pass on my BIOS just in case (I'm a paranoiac). This time I tried to set it, introduced it slowly to see I introduce it correctly, confirmed it, it was accepted. When I turn the laptop on, it does not want to accept it. Guys, just for you to understand, I'm really desperate =(

Is there a way to reset it (may be by disassembling it somehow)?

Please Help!

Comment: try this and tell me if it worked: http://www.wikihow.com/Break-a-BIOS-Password

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar problem on t300l.
When password is required, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>. The system asks you for a rescue password.

A [list of such passwords is available on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/L3c3rySj). Example of the first ones:

```
2002-01-02 ALAA4ABA
2002-01-03 A4219DAA
2002-01-04 AA4HBBLA
2002-01-05 AAAALO0B
2002-01-06 A2BBAAAL
2002-01-07 A0BB00LD
```

Comment: The password changes each day. You will need to ask Asus for a new one.

Comment: Try removing the CMOS battery for a while. Might reset the date to on of those in the list.

Comment: After reseting the date, this list worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question has been here unattended for a while.
In the end, I got my device to a registered Asus service center, and the cost of the reset was around 30 USD.

I no longer own the device, but just a note, the issue was in the BIOS version. The password I had set included digits and both lowercase and uppercase letter, and the issue was in the lower/upper case part. I did eventually update the BIOS and everything was well on, but just wanted to make note to be careful when setting the password.