# How to generate Asus BIOS rescue password?

Tags: laptop, uefi, password-recovery, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS laptop. The problem is that I've forgot my BIOS password.

I've clicked <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in order to get a date upon which a rescue password would be generated. The date is that of today `2014/10/05`.

Does anyone know how to generate the master password of my transformer book?

Comment: I can't access the CMOS battery in my laptop as this either would damage it or remove it from the warranty. There is already a second approach to recover things which is the Master Password generation which depends on today's date.

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately!!

Comment: Then contact the ASUS people concerning this issue.  If it was easy to change and bypass the Master Password, it would not be a very good protection would it?

Comment: I forgot to ask and verify, YOU DO OWN the laptop in question.  If not, then I would refer this back to your company administrator.

Comment: [How to clear an unknown BIOS or CMOS password](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000235.htm)

Comment: YES/NO I own it won't make sense! Because you don't have the right neither to Ask or Verify!!! @mdpc
However, I've just contacted the ASUS support who are the only one who have this right!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resetting Bios Password on ASUS Transformer T300L](http://superuser.com/questions/755589/resetting-bios-password-on-asus-transformer-t300l)

Answer (score -1):

Change date as user to 2002/01/02 and use recovery password ALAA4ABA (all uppercase)

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?