# Changing BIOS password leads to error (BIOS bug)

Tags: motherboard, bios, passwords

I have Asus X453MA notebook with Windows 8.1 Single Language (OEM).

The BIOS program has 2 passwords: one for BIOS accessing called Administrator password and the other for HDD booting called User password. I successfully edited the Administrator password at that time and would proceed to editing the User password. The error occured when I was supplying the old User password before I could enter the new User password. The old User password was not accepted by the BIOS program, which I concluded a bug, plus I could not exit the BIOS gracefully because the exit button has malfunction.

As of now 2016-07-27, Asus always redirect me to their service centers instead of helping me to replace the unit or motherboard. Their service center is charging me Php 4,500.00 for motherboard replacement since they do not have the Jig Board for BIOS reprogramming.

Is that right to pay for a repair service which was caused primarily by a bug of just changing passwords? What legal actions regarding Information Technology may I do?

Asus Main and Asus Philippines always redirect me to their service centers instead of assisting the issue directly. They said that they are now fixing the bug by their senior engineers, but still they want me to pay for a bug error which is very illogical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have forgot your BIOS password. If not, then its malfunctioning. Whatever the case, BIOS password is not something that should me messed up. You can completely poweroff your machine for at least 5-10 minutes, then try to change it again. If the problem still persists, then follow the steps to reset the password:

Only one step: Open up your laptop and remove the **CMOS** **battery** for at least 15-30 min and put it back. It will **reset** all **BIOS** settings. Next time you boot up, it won't remember your old password. So you only need to set a new password or use the old one if you like.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I opened the laptop but the CMOS battery is seemingly missing as well as the CPU heat sink. However, the CPU fan is present far below the CPU. Maybe the solution will be disconnecting the laptop battery. I already solved the solution by software configuration, not hardware by this [link](http://superuser.com/questions/820974/how-to-generate-asus-bios-rescue-password).

Comment: Good to know that you're no longer facing the issue. Thank you.