# How to reset the BIOS password on a Dell Latitude?

Tags: bios, passwords, dell-latitude

I need to reset the the admin password for BIOS on a Dell Latitude... I never set one but it just popped up when I tried to access BIOS.

Comment: See if this link http://superuser.com/questions/1046104/cant-enter-bios-password-containing/1046114#1046114) is useful

Comment: I may be able to generate you a master password from your service tag or serial number.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully unlock the BIOS password for an E6230 using the following site:

> From DELL forums:
> https://bios-pw.org/ seems to work on every Dell laptop I have owned you could try it. -elpro999

[Dogbert's Blog - BIOS Password Backdoors in Laptops](http://dogber1.blogspot.com/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html)

The trick is you must use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the generated password to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

First try disconnecting power to the PC and then removing the BIOS battery from the motherboard for 10 minutes. This will typically reset the BIOS to factory defaults.

If this doesn't work, download the same BIOS version from the motherboard manufacturer and re-flash your mobo. This will also reset your motherboard to factory defaults. It might also be worth flashing the BIOS to the latest version once you regain access.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure will depend on the model of your Dell Latitude (e.g. E6400, ...), as well as on the BIOS version. In the BIOS, your the Service Tag of your laptop should end with something like "-####". Those four digits depends on which version of the BIOS is installed. You must search for a solution that is compatible with those four digits.